# MySQL Error - ADD PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, key, primary-key

i have a big error in my mysql server.
MySQL have crash yesterday, but all is ok.
If i want to make update today, i have a problem with add primary key.
I need ADD PRIMARY KEY to table A13_product
here is create script

```
CREATE TABLE `A13_product` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`users_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`product_set_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`producer_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`photos_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`photogallery_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`price` DECIMAL(15,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`price_recycling` DECIMAL(15,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`description_short` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`description_long` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`description_long_en` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`description_long_de` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`description_long_sk` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`has_comments` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`active` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`warranty` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`date_add` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`date_edit` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`view_count` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`url` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`sticky` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`delivery_date` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`possible_buy` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`var1` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var3` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var4` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var5` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`poradi` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`tax_rates_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`cache_url` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`description_en` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`name_en` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`ics` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var_cz` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var_en` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`branch` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`cast` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`podc` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`weight` DECIMAL(15,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`image` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`stupen` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci'
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Here is a SQL command , what i need execute

```
ALTER TABLE A13_product ADD PRIMARY KEY(`id`);
```

And error is

```
SQL Error (156): Table 'c2****.A13_product#1' already exists
```

in the table does not use a key, and when I give DROP key, so he tells me that the table has no key

When I look into INFORMATION_SCHEMA in Table TABLE_contrastion no key to the table A13_product

Does anyone know please, where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't drop a NOT NULL constraint on a column the way you can a foreign key or an index, or a default. 
This might be the reason why you can't drop the primary key, if it exists.
Instead, just use the 'change' or 'modify' syntax and leave off the NOT NULL bit:

```
alter table A13_product modify id INT(11) default null;
```

Any pre-existing indexes or foreign keys on the column are not affected.
Then, try to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE A13_product DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(id,id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your Create table structure to:

```
CREATE TABLE `A13_product` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`users_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`product_set_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`producer_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`photos_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`photogallery_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`price` DECIMAL(15,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`price_recycling` DECIMAL(15,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`description_short` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`description_long` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`description_long_en` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`description_long_de` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`description_long_sk` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`has_comments` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`active` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`warranty` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`date_add` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`date_edit` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`view_count` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`url` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`sticky` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`delivery_date` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`possible_buy` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`var1` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var3` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var4` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var5` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`poradi` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`tax_rates_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`cache_url` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`description_en` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`name_en` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`ics` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var_cz` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var_en` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`branch` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`cast` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`podc` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`weight` DECIMAL(15,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`image` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`stupen` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci'
CREATE TABLE `A13_product` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`users_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`product_set_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`producer_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`photos_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`photogallery_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`price` DECIMAL(15,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`price_recycling` DECIMAL(15,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`description_short` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`description_long` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`description_long_en` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`description_long_de` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`description_long_sk` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`has_comments` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`active` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`warranty` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`date_add` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`date_edit` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`view_count` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`url` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`sticky` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`delivery_date` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`possible_buy` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`var1` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var3` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var4` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var5` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`poradi` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`tax_rates_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`cache_url` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`description_en` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`name_en` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`ics` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var_cz` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`var_en` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`branch` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`cast` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`podc` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`weight` DECIMAL(15,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`image` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
`stupen` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```